# Python open default terminal, execute commands, keep open, AND then allow user-input

Tags: python, command-line, terminal

I'm wanting to open a terminal from a Python script (not one marked as executable, but actually doing python3 myscript.py to run it), have the terminal run commands, and then keep the terminal open and let the user type commands into it.

EDIT (as suggested): I am primarily needing this for Linux (I'm using Xubuntu, Ubuntu and stuff like that). It would be really nice to know Windows 7/8 and Mac methods, too, since I'd like a cross-platform solution in the long-run. Input for any system would be appreciated, however.

---

Just so people know some useful stuff pertaining to this, here's some code that may be difficult to come up with without some research. This doesn't allow user-input, but it does keep the window open. The code is specifically for Linux:

```
import subprocess, shlex;
myFilePathString="/home/asdf asdf/file.py";
params=shlex.split('x-terminal-emulator -e bash -c "python3 \''+myFilePathString+'\'; echo \'(Press any key to exit the terminal emulator.)\'; read -n 1 -s"');
subprocess.call(params);
```

To open it with the Python interpreter running afterward, which is about as good, if not better than what I'm looking for, try this:

```
import subprocess, shlex;
myFilePathString="/home/asdf asdf/file.py";
params=shlex.split('x-terminal-emulator -e bash -c "python3 -i \''+myFilePathString+'\'"');
subprocess.call(params);
```

I say these examples may take some time to come up with because passing parameters to bash, which is being opened within another command can be problematic without taking a few steps. Plus, you need to know to use to quotes in the right places, or else, for example, if there's a space in your file path, then you'll have problems and might not know why.

EDIT: For clarity (and part of the answer), I found out that there's a standard way to do this in Windows:

```
cmd /K [whatever your commands are]
```

So, if you don't know what I mean try that and see what happens. Here's the URL where I found the information: http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html

Comment: umm on windows its `cmd.exe -c "command1;command2;..."`  I think(it may be a different switch depending on if you want to keep it open, I cant recall of the top of my head)... what are you actually trying to accomplish though ... there are very few valid use cases that I can see where this would be the desired behaviour

Comment: Thanks. I'm making a run shortcut for a Python text editor. I want it to open a terminal, run the script in the editor, and stay open, showing the output, while allowing the user to do whatever needed on the terminal thereafter. Either way, they need to see the output and close the Window. Might as well offer the extra functionality of being able to use that open terminal (and it's a personal programming preference, I have).

Comment: It's kind of like F5 in SciTE, except I want it to actually open up the system's terminal instead of having its own—SciTE's built-in one doesn't work with such as the input statement (and other things).

Comment: This probably will depend on the platform, and possibly even on desktop environment. Could you specify those in the question?

Comment: In the meantime, I guess I can always just open a terminal in the current directory and let the user run the script manually. Or have a shortcut for that, one for a run/close system and another for run and stay open (without allowing user-input). No need to choose one.

Comment: Yeah. Allowing multiple options is working out pretty well. Having it run python -i myprogram.py (so the interpreter is open afterward) is pretty nice and maybe better than just having the command-line still open, since I can check and manipulate the variables that the program was using, or had access to. But yeah, I'd still love to know the answer, for anyone who knows.